# How to unittest setup.py

Tags: python, pip

I have a class named **ConfigInstantiator** which has some logic in **setup.py**.

I want to test this class.

I assume that when setup.py is called, my package is **not ready** yet, so moving this class into one of the module of my package doesn't work. (Am I right?)

I tried to:

```
import setup
```

in unit test, but it conflicts with **PyCharm**'s setup.py.

Do you know if there is a way to unittest this class?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: @SmartManoj I can import setup.py correctly now. But the setup.py runs setup function, it fails when being imported in unit test environment.

Comment: Is there a way to import setup.py without running 'setup' function?

Answer (score 0):

1. As @SmartManoj suggested, use technology suggested in [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)
2. Put setup function inside block:

   ```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
   ```